# When redirecting from page my data is lost

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my javascript with which I send data with ajax of my form to an action in my ruby controller

```
$scope.pay_spei = function () {
        $('#pay_spei').attr("disabled", true);
        var concepts = JSON.stringify($scope.transaction_spei.getConcepts());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/payment_spei/charge',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                payment_spei: concepts
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS!");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        }).success(function () {
            window.location.href = "/payment_spei/charge";
        });

    };
```

In my console:

```
Processing by PaymentSpeiController#charge as */*
  Parameters: {"payment_spei"=>"[{\"name\":\"bbbbb\",\"quantity\":12,\"unit_price\":10000,\"$$hashKey\":\"object:3\"}]"}
{"payment_spei"=>"[{\"name\":\"bbbbb\",\"quantity\":12,\"unit_price\":10000,\"$$hashKey\":\"object:3\"}]", "controller"=>"payment_spei", "action"=>"charge"}
```

in the action of my controller called charge these data disappear:

```
def charge
concepts = JSON.parse(params[:payment_spei])
end
```

throws me this error

> TypeError in PaymentSpeiController#charge 
>   no implicit conversion of nil into String

this error does not appear when I remove the redirect in javascript

```
 window.location.href = "/payment_spei/charge"
```

I need to redirect from page, how could I solve this error?

Comment: What do you have in routes.rb? Why POST and GET (`window.location.href` gives it) requests go to the same controller action `charge`?